# I get [object htmlparagraphelement] where I am trying to get the value of the textbox input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to return the value of a text input to a paragraph tag, but I get 
[object htmlparagraphelement] instead. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test").keyup(function(){
            var str = $( this ).val();
            str = str.toLowerCase;
            $("#result").text(str);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="test" value=""></input>
<p id="result">?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `toLowerCase` is a function, so you need `()` following it to actually execute it.

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    $("#result").text(str);
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6kwvyxge/)